# Flutter ListView Dynamic Height of Element Based on Content

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I have a widget with a listview in flutter. This listview contains 3 items:

1. Textfield
2. Image picker
3. Another textfield

When I create the listview there is a defined height for both textfields. For the imagepicker the height should depend on the case if just shows the button to select an image or if an image has already been selected. In that case I want the image to fit the width.
So far I am only able to set some fixed sizes for the height which is working. But I like to have this dynamically chosen base on the selected image.

Return element of the image picker:

```
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child:                Image.file(_image),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: fireStackItems,
                  )
                ],
              )
            )
```

Element of the listview where the image is shown and where I would like to not have the fixed height (deleting it results in an error for a infinite height):

```
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
        child: new MyImagePicker(
              myImagePickerController: myImagePickerController,
            ),
      )
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks and kind regards,

tank

Update:
To show what I want to achieve I added the following image:
[image]

So after clicking the Button I want to show the Image that should fill the width of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using an Expanded widget, which tries to be as big as possible. If you remove the Expanded widget and just move all the children up, you should just be able to set the width of the image however you want and the height will scale accordingly.

Comment: If I remove the "Expanded" the image has a "Bottom Overflow" area and I get the following error:════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Staggered List Package?

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-

It looks like it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks definitely interesting. Unfortunately I have restructured my app in a way that I cannot test it anymore. But will keep that in mind.